# Linking functions with LD_PRELOAD at runtime

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I am writing a lib that intercepts the calls to `malloc` and `free` at runtime by running the program with `LD_PRELOAD=mylib myexe`.

The calls to `malloc` and `free` are intercept fine. My problem is that there's another function in mylib that I also want intercepted when `LD_PRELOAD` is used and I cannot figure out why it doesn't 'just work' like the calls to `malloc` and `free`.

In mylib.c:

```
void* malloc(size_t s)
{
    return doMyMalloc();
}

void free(void* p)
{
    doMyFree(p);
}

void otherThing(size_t)
{
    doThing();
}
```

In myexe.cpp:

```
#include <malloc.h>

extern "C" void otherThing(size_t);  // Compile with -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-all

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    void* x = malloc(1000);   // Successfully intercepted.
    free(x);  // Successfully intercepted.
    otherThing(1);  // Segfault.
}
```

One way I have managed to get it to work is by doing:

```
typedef void (*FUNC)(size_t);
FUNC otherThing = NULL;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    otherThing = (FUNC)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "otherThing");
    otherThing(1);  // Successfully calls mylib's otherThing().
}
```

but I don't want to write all this code; I don't have to do it for `malloc` and `free`.
It's ok if the program crashes if the `LD_PRELOAD` prefix is missing.

Comment: are you compiling your exe with -lmylib?

Comment: @auselen Ok that works, but the problem is that now both `malloc` and `free` are always 'intercepted' even if I don't use `LD_PRELOAD`. I don't want that, I want it to only use mylib if `LD_PRELOAD` is used.

Comment: Easiest would be to divide them into two shared libraries. I would suggest you to use pen/paper to draft your problem. These things can turn into chicken-egg problem easily.

Comment: What is the nature of the segmentation fault? Where does it happen? Is it the crash in `otherThing()`, or is it in `doThing()` or something called from it, or is it in the code that is calling `otherThing()`? I'm not sure exactly what it will tell you, but I'm sure the distinctions are important.  In particular, if the problem is in `doThing()` or something it calls, then the problem is not directly the preload mechanism. If you compile without the `-Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-all` option, do you get complaints about `malloc()` and `free()`, or only `otherThing()`? Is that significant?

Comment: Why ignore unresolved symbols?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you're applying a single solution (`LD_PRELOAD`) to solve two different problems.  First, you want to patch `malloc()` and `free()`.  You've got that working--great.  Next, you want to have a runtime "plug-in" system where you don't link against any library at build time, but only do so at runtime.  This is typically done using `dlopen()` and `dlsym()`, and I recommend you use those.

The idea is that you don't want to specify a particular implementation of `otherThing()` at build time, but you do need to have some implementation at runtime (or you rightly expect to crash).  So let's be explicit about it and use `dlsym()` to resolve the function name at runtime, of course with error detection in case it's not found.

As for where to define `otherThing()`, it can be in a totally separate file given to `dlopen()`, or in `mylib` (in which case pass NULL as the filename to `dlopen()`).

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a gotcha. There are several posts relating to this on the internet, but I'll try to break it down to 'getting it to work'.

If this is under Linux, then what has happened is that the app has been compiled to not be able to use the external symbol. The quickest solution is to add the same compilation flags to the main application as are used in the library i.e. add the `-fPIC` flag to the compilation of the main application, just like it is done for the library.

Rather than using the `-Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-all` flag, you should be using the `__attribute__ ((weak))` for the function, like:

```
extern "C" void otherThing(size_t) __attribute__ ((weak);
```

And checking it for NULL at run-time, which will allow you to determine if it's been set or not.

By compiling the main application in the same way as a `.so`, you are implicitly allowing it to be used itself as a target for `LD_PRELOAD` as, by the manual page:

**LD_PRELOAD**

> A list of additional, user-specified, ELF shared libraries to be
>                 loaded before all others.  The items of the list can be separated by
>                 spaces or colons.  This can be used to selectively **override
>                 functions in other shared libraries**.